# convert an image to a decimal value [Python]

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, decimal, data-conversion

I'm using opencv with python, and I want to convert an image to a decimal value to store it in a text document.

I tried to use b64encode, but it returns str or string value, but I want a decimal value.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are expecting? Bas64 will just provide a representation for the raw data.

Comment: but if you want to store as text, then you need it as string,no?

Comment: import cv2
import base64
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
(tmp,buffer) = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
imcode = base64.b64encode(buffer)
print(imcode)

Comment: I want it as a decimal value, of course I will store it in a text document, but I want to use it later as a variable, and modify it

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need decimal values. Base64 is much more compact than storing the RGB values as strings of decimals. And it's easy to convert the Base64 data back into a binary file.

Comment: The only situation that I can think of for using decimal is if the image dimensions are very small and you have a greyscale or palette-mapped image. Then you can print the decimalized image on the page so that the image structure is still kind-of visible.

Comment: [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) ?

Comment: I want to store a 50x50 image into a text file, then I want to compare it with some other images to see the compatibility percentage.

Comment: That's why I want a decimal value to facilitate the comparaison between the stored image and the others

Comment: So, is that feasible or no?

Comment: @TariqTALBI aren't there any other ways to compare images?

Comment: @JeruLuke yes there is (you know) , but I want to try this

Comment: @TariqTALBI maybe you should show example of one pixel stored as decimal. Assume your image was 1px by 1px and is red, do you want to store (in text file) as hex value `FF0000` ..or as decimal value `16711680`? A whole image (many pixels) cannot be processed into just one single decimal number representing all the pixel colours and shades in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why would want to convert images to decimal values. Nevertheless there is a naïve approach.

As mentioned in the code provided by you, first obtain the `imcode`:

```
import cv2 
import base64 
image = cv2.imread(path + 'date.jpg') 
(tmp,buffer) = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image) 
imcode = base64.b64encode(buffer)
```

Then you can obtain the ASCII value of each character in `imcode` using:

`ascii_value = [ord(c) for c in imcode]`

Now `ascii_value` is a list of integers which you can convert to decimal values.

I would suggest you to have a look at [THIS LINK](https://pypi.org/project/text-to-image/) as well

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a pretty naive idea (sorry) and can't work.

In the first place, a 50x50 binary image already has 2500 bits. An RGB image would take 60000 bits. A standard floating-point representation (32 or 64 bits) is out of question and you would need some BigNum representation.

But, worse, if the goal is to compare images, the pixels will get widely differing weights and the numerical difference will give you a very poor measure of the discrepancies.

You'd better have a look at the so-called similarity scores.